# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of null

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-foundation

My column Jurisdiction is a multichoice column. 
My program is as below :

```
for (var index = 0; index < ArrayRetrieved.Jurisdiction.results.length; index++)
    $('#jurisdiction option[value="' + ArrayRetrieved.Jurisdiction.results[index] + '"]').prop('selected', true)
    $("#jurisdiction").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

I get this error : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of null**.
how i can resolve this please?

Comment: try it as `if(ArrayRetrieved.Jurisdiction){
 for (var index = 0; index < ArrayRetrieved.Jurisdiction.results.length; index++)
  $('#jurisdiction option[value="' + ArrayRetrieved.Jurisdiction.results[index] + '"]').prop('selected', true)
  $("#jurisdiction").trigger("chosen:updated");
}`

Comment: Yessss thnx! it work :)

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250342/list-items-from-sharepoint-list-are-empty-error can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a null check before the for loop.

Modify your code as below:

```
if(ArrayRetrieved.Jurisdiction){ 
    for (var index = 0; index < ArrayRetrieved.Jurisdiction.results.length; index++) 
    $('#jurisdiction option[value="' + ArrayRetrieved.Jurisdiction.results[index] + '"]').prop('selected', true) 
    $("#jurisdiction").trigger("chosen:updated"); 
}
```