# List items from SharePoint list are empty -> error

Tags: sharepoint-list

I have a beginner question. I am using an ajax call to get elements of a sharepoint list choice(checkboxes) column called "Orbit" to create a google pie chart:

```
data.d.results.forEach(function(row) {
    // each row
    row.Orbit.results.forEach(function(choiceOrbit) {
        // each choice of Orbit of single row
        if (countOrbit.hasOwnProperty(choiceOrbit)) {
            countOrbit[choiceOrbit] += 1;
        } else {
            countOrbit[choiceOrbit] = 1;
        }
    });
```

But if the item **EDIT: (if the row is empty)**  i get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of null
at Statistics.aspx:658
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (Statistics.aspx:632)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at A (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

How can i add an if(), so that an empty item will be neglected in the counting?
Something like:

```
if(row.Wavebands.results.forEach!=null)
```

doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct answer is:

```
data.d.results.forEach(function(row) {
  // each row
  if (row.hasOwnProperty('Orbit') && row.Orbit != null) {
    row.Orbit.results.forEach(function(choiceOrbit) {
      // each choice of Orbit of single row
      if (countOrbit.hasOwnProperty(choiceOrbit)) {
          countOrbit[choiceOrbit] += 1;
      } else {
          countOrbit[choiceOrbit] = 1;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to check the **length** of the `data.result`

```
 if(data.d.results.length > 0)
  {
    // Add your code

  }
```

Comment: doesnt work.... not the whole column is empty, only one item ( so one of the forEach)

Comment: in the column  of the sharepoint list, some rows are empty. this is causing the problem

Comment: Okay try to check **if(row!=null)** before going to **foreach**

Comment: its not working. Both before and after row.Orbit.results.forEach(function(choiceOrbit)

Comment: This will also not work if the list is initially empty, and you're trying to figure out if someone has written anything to it before you write an item. It will complain that the list doesn't exist (even though it does).